# auto-covariance matrix for 1D array

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I want to compute auto-covariance matrix for real valued 1D array . I have seen in a blog that auto-correlation matrix is computed as below .

```
import numpy as np
x = np.asarray([1+1j,2+1j,3-1j]) 
acf = np.convolve(x,np.conj(x)[::-1])
Rxx=acf[2:]; # R_xx(0) is the center element
Rx = toeplitz(Rxx,np.hstack((Rxx[0], np.conj(Rxx[1:]))))
```

I am able to compute Auto-correlation matrix for real valued also with code snippet above.
I want to understand how auto-covariance matrix can be computed similarly?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html ?

Comment: I am not looking for covariance matrix.  In the example above auto correlation (acf)  is computed (which is 1D array) later converted to toeplitz matrix.  Now I want to do same thing except replace auto correlation with auto covariance.

Comment: Ho do you imagine calculating auto-covariance  on single 1D signal? I think this is main problem of your question. `toeplitz` seems irrelevant here, as it just creates matrix out of two 1D arrays. So i guess last line will not be changed.